# UWP ContentDialog Invocation

Tags: mvvm, modal-dialog, winrt-xaml, uwp, template10

I am using UWP and Template 10 to build a GUI app by following MVVM pattern. As a part of application I need to invoke a content dialog by pressing button on Main Page. So separate ContentDialog was created in standalone .xaml file for that purpose:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="UWP1.Views.Speech"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWP1.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Dictate"
    PrimaryButtonText="Accept"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick"
    >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Margin="15" Content="Dictate" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button  Margin="15" Content="Clear Text" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Tap 'Dictate', and speak" FontSize="12" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0 10 0 0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Message Dication" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"  />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="300">
            <TextBox Margin="5 5 5 10"  AcceptsReturn="True"  />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

What is the proper way to open/invoke it in my Main Page by pressing button (as I need to keep logic separated for view and viewmodel)?

How I do it now:

From Main Page I invoke DictateCommand, which in turn creates an instance of ContentDialog and shows it:

```
 <AppBarButton Grid.Column="1" Icon="Microphone" IsCompact="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding DictateCommand}"/>

        public ICommand DictateCommand { get; set; }

        public async void Dictate(object obj)
        {
            var contentDialog = new Speech();
            await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

It looks like a MVVM pattern breach for me. Could you please help me to do it in a right way?

EDIT:

I have implemented dialog service and injected it in the main view model.
However, I got another obstacle. For this dialog I created separate view model and property which encapsulates dialog text box value. When I press 'accept' button on the dialog - I need this value to be reflected on my Main View. So I need to pass dialog's text box value from dialog's view model to main view model. Should I perform another dependency injection to deal with it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have four options.

**ONE** The first is a service, just like @Ask-too-much explains. In fact, this is a beautiful solution if you like it.

> The benefits of the first solution are that it is reusable. If you are not reusing this UI, a dedicated service might be overkill, to be honest.

**TWO** The second is a view-model event. That is to say, your Page can subscribe to your view-model's event (let's call it ShowContentDialog) and when it is raised by the view-model, your Page handle its presentation.

> The benefits this approach is that, just like the first approach, you are offloading the effort to another class. In this case, you are creating what is likely a one-off solution without needing a service, a service interface, or injection of that service somehow. If you are not waiting for the result of the event, then I think this is idea for 99% of issues like yours.

**THREE** The third approach is to use a different control that can be bound to a property. For example, since you are already using Template 10, you can use the ModalDialog control which has an IsModal property. A property in your view-model (let's call it IsModalVisible) can be used to control the dialog without coupling to it.

> The good part of this is that you get to invoke the dialog from the logic of your view-model, just like the first two approaches. But unlike the first, you do not need a service. Unlike the second, you do not need a handler. It's the most "data binding" way to do it, and likely what I would do.

**FOUR** The fourth way to do it is to use messaging. Messaging is the mechanism one view-model uses to communicate with another. IN this case you could use messaging from your view-model (with a message we might call ShowDialog) that is listened for, not in another view-model, but in your Page. This would work fine, too.

> The down side to this is that you need a messaging solution, but you might already have that. The up-side is that the logic for handling the visual could be relocated at any time as Messaging is multicasted to anyone listening.

If I were you, I would consider number 3 first, perhaps. Without a little more understanding of your app scenario, I can't be sure. You are a developer, though. All four of those options are good. Just be sure not to be tempted into passing the UIElement into your view-model. That's needless nastiness :)

Best of luck!

Comment: With option Three, would the modal dialog be created the same as in Template 10's Search Sample project? I need a dialog where the user can press "yes" or "no" and I need to know in my ViewModel that invokes the Dialog which option they picked...but I'm unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

Suggested solution in MVVM is don't create instance of `Speech Dialog` directly in ViewModel, create `SpeechDialogService`.

```
public interface ISpeechDialogService
{
    Task ShowAsync();
}

public class SpeechDialogService : ISpeechDialogService
{
    public async Task ShowAsync()
    {
        var contentDialog = new Speech();
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();

    }
}
```

And inject this service in your `ViewModel` constructor

```
public class AbcViewModel
{
    readonly ISpeechDialogService _dialog;

    public AbcViewModel(ISpeechDialogService dialog)
    {
        _dialog = dialog;
    }

    public async void Dictate(object obj)
    {
        await _dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```